# GPS without PPS vs. GPS with PPS vs. NTP

Tags: time, ntp, gps

With which time synchronization method I can achieve more accuracy to the absolute UTC time? I use GPS with PPS for now but I want to compare these sources.

Assume the following items:

- Internet is availible
- May two cases, NTP via internet or LAN

Ideally with indication of source.

- Based on the rule of thumb I found about NTP 5-100ms.
- GPS due to serial line, interrupt delay should be worse.
- GPS with PPS < 1ms.

Are these values more or less correct?

Answer (score 1):

See [this article](http://www.satsignal.eu/ntp/Raspberry-Pi-NTP.html) that handles exactly your question. That source confirms your ranking, but reports about a factor of 10 better precision than the numbers you mention:

- NTP from WAN: +/- 5000 microseconds
- NTP FROM stratum-1 source on LAN: +/- 500 microseconds
- Trimble Resolution-SMT timing GPS module: +/- 15 microseconds
- u-blox NEO-6M GPS module: +/- 15 microseconds

As for the performance of GPS without PPS, the same site (different article), [here](http://www.satsignal.eu/ntp/FreeBSD-GPS-PPS.htm), reports:

> Initial tests with just the serial 4800 baud NMEA output and no PPS
>   using Windows were disappointing.  Whilst the device worked, the
>   accuracy and jitter were no better than could be achieved with a
>   broadband Internet connection and servers from the NTP pool.

And about that same solution, at the end of that article:

> At the default setting, 4800 baud, each bit occupies 0.2ms, and the
>   uncertainty with which the GPS sends out the data, and the operating
>   system can report the time the data was received, result in a somewhat
>   higher short term offset jitter, and no better daily drift than with
>   multiple Internet sources.  You may be able to do better using a high
>   baud rate, and perhaps with a USB-connected GPS and a much higher high
>   baud rate.  It's possible that the jitter would be less with a UNIX
>   system, but I've not tested that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Found that site before too. All GPS modules use PPS. Did you also know/find the accuracy without PPS?

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for editing. Yes I found this Google hits months ago too and implemented GPS with PPS. I thought there may will be more validated information and details about accuracy.